# How to remove white space from multi line string value in Python without using regular expression

Tags: python

I have a string value printing in multiple lines. I used three single/double quotes for assigning string value

```
artist = """
       Mariah
       Carey
       """
 name = 'My all'
 realeased_year = 1997
 genre = 'Latin'
 duration_seconds = 231

print(f'{artist}(full name has {len(artist.strip().replace(" ", ""))} characters) and her song \'{name}\' was released in {realeased_year + 1}')
```

[image]
**It outputs wrong number of characters: 12**

However, when I assign a string value in one line like

```
artist = 'Mariah Carey'
```

I have correct number of **characters 11**
[image]

Is it possible to remove all white spaces (leading, middle and trailing) from multi line string value without using regular expressions

Comment: If you try to artist = "Marian Carey" and print(len(artist.strip())). You will find the same 12 Character length output. Please Check again.

Answer (score 3):

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) splits a string on whitespace so you could do this:

```
>>> artist = """
...        Mariah
...        Carey
...        """
>>> ' '.join(artist.split())
'Mariah Carey'
```

This will split the string into a list of words. Those words are then joined with a single space delimiter.

I assumed that you would want to retain one interword space, however, if you want to get rid of all whitespace then join with an empty string:

```
>>> ''.join(artist.split())
'MariahCarey'
```

Modify your display string:

```
>>> print(f'{artist}(full name has {len("".join(artist.split()))} characters)')

   Mariah
   Carey
   (full name has 11 characters)
```

Comment: do you think you can provide a complete version for your answer ? 
running into syntax error 
Thanks

Comment: @DurdonaA.: looks like a complete version to me... I've cut and paste verbatim from terminal.

Comment: formatting with {f""} getting a syntax error

Comment: Use double quotes like this: `"".join()`

Comment: @DurdonaA.: you're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer if you think it answers your question.

Comment: @DurdonaA. Acceptable solution.

Comment: @avio8 yeah I think so thanks for your efforts too

Answer (score 1):

When you use triple quotes and use enter to separate your lines, python inserts `\n` character which is also added to the total number of characters. So in the following line

```
print(f'{artist}(full name has {len(artist.strip().replace(" ", ""))} characters) and her song \'{name}\' was released in {realeased_year + 1}')
```

in the replace function instead of a `" "` use `"\n"`.

Comment: getting an error 

SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash

Comment: If you have to or want to use f-string then you can assign `len(artist.strip().replace(" ", ""))` to a variable and use that variable in your `print` statement. eg. `length = len(artist.strip().replace(" ", ""))` and use length in `print`.

Comment: Its work perfectly as per the question requirement.